# Paypal customer checkout with rails adaptive payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal

Has any successfully set the header image in the `displayOptions.headerImageUrl` with adaptive payments in Ruby? I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

From my understanding, I have one action `set_pay_chained` that gets the paykey and calls the pay function, but need to create an entirely different function to just tell PayPal the image url. Is this correct? Does anyone have an example of how to do this in Ruby/Rails?

Currently my code basically looks like this.

```
def set_pay_chained 

  @host=request.host.to_s
  @port=request.port.to_s   
  @cancelURL= params[:returnurl_paypal]
  #@returnURL="http://#{@host}:#{@port}/websamples/ap/setpaychained/pay_details"  
  @returnURL= params[:returnurl_paypal]
  @@ep["SERVICE"]="/AdaptivePayments/Pay" 
  @caller =  PayPalSDKCallers::Caller.new(false)
  req={     
    "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
    "clientDetails.ipAddress"=>@@clientDetails["ipAddress"],
    "clientDetails.deviceId" =>@@clientDetails["deviceId"],
    "clientDetails.applicationId" => @@clientDetails["applicationId"],
    "feesPayer"=> "PRIMARYRECEIVER",
    "receiverList.receiver[0].email"=>params[:receiveremail_0],    
    "receiverList.receiver[1].email"=> params[:receiveremail_1],
    "receiverList.receiver[0].amount"=>params[:amount_0],
    "receiverList.receiver[1].amount"=>params[:amount_1],
    "receiverList.receiver[0].primary[0]"=> "true",
    "receiverList.receiver[1].primary[1]"=> "false",

    "currencyCode"=> "USD",
    "actionType"=>"PAY",
    "returnUrl" => @returnURL,
    "cancelUrl"=>"#{@cancelURL}&paykey=#{@paykey}", 
  }
  @transaction = @caller.call(req)

  if (@transaction.success?)
    session[:setpaychained_response]=@transaction.response    
    @response = session[:setpaychained_response]
    @paykey = @response["payKey"][0]
    @paymentExecStatus=@response["paymentExecStatus"]

    if (@paymentExecStatus.to_s=="COMPLETED")
      redirect_to :controller => 'setpaychained',:action => 'pay_details'
    else
      redirect_to  "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=#{@paykey}" 
    end
  else
    session[:paypal_error]=@transaction.response
    redirect_to :controller => 'calls', :action => 'error'
  end
rescue Errno::ENOENT => exception
  flash[:error] = exception
  redirect_to :controller => 'calls', :action => 'exception'
end
```

== Update ==
On Paypal's developer forms, I've been given a variety of advice. I've moved the discussion here to see if I could get a more "rails" way of handling this. So far, SweatCoder has provided what I think is the closest solution I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the code is in PHP (which I have only a very, very, basic understanding) so I'm now trying to translate this code (https://www.x.com/message/211714#211714) into ruby. My understanding is that I need to make two separate calls. I can't tell if I'm supposed to make these calls simultaneously and if not, which call should come first.

Comment: (For others stumbling across this: James his question was answered in https://www.x.com/message/211581 (use SetPaymentsOptions)

Comment: Hey @Robert, I actually moved the discussion over to stackoverflow to try and get a more Ruby/Rails way of approaching this. SweetCoder provided a PHP example of how to do this (https://www.x.com/message/211714#211714). I think this is closer to what I'm attempting. I'm now trying to translate this into Ruby.